# Django Heroku and postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I am new to publishing django apps on heroku.
I have read their tutorials and figured I would start simple by modifying their [template django project](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template).

So far everything was good.

Then I made an app as one does, made a model and ran

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations my_app
python3 manage.py migrate
```

and things seemed ok.

I then pushed to heroku and there were no immediate complaints.

However, now when I try to make save a new model I get the error:

```
ProgrammingError at /my_app/
relation "my_app_myappmodel" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "my_app_myappmodel" ("field1", "field2", "field3") VALUES...
```

odd...

So I run this locally and everything works fine.

I have tried cleaning my migrations, faking my migrations, squashing my migrations, etc (as other S.O. posts suggest)

Nothing works.

What is up and how do I fix it?

Comment: how much migrations did you have, may be you can add code here?

Comment: @BearBrown it is literally just the initial

Comment: Have you run "migrate" on heroku instance?

Comment: @AamirAdnan how is that different than running migrate locally and pushing the git repo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually run the migrations on Heroku once you have pushed the code generated by `makemigrations`. You do this via `heroku run manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 2):

run the following command from your terminal

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

or you can also do:

in your local `settings.py`, change your `DATABASES` variable to use the heroku one then run from the terminal

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

but you should not normally locally make changes to the heroku production database (as in option 2) except if you are really desperate or don't care